# Rails ActiveRecord find array of ids, but some are not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to find a model by an array of ids like so:

```
Model.find [1,2,3]
```

but let's say only two of these models exist (the model with id of 2 was deleted):

```
#<Model id: 1>
#<Model id: 3>
```

I get an error like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Models with 'id': (1, 2, 3) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3).>
```

Is it possible to catch this error and determine which of the models were not present?

say i'm in my controller:

```
def index
  @models = Model.find params.require(:model_ids)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  e.full_message
  ???
end
```

I'd like to, in the `???` line, run some code on the exception `e` that will return `2`, letting me know what of the models was not found, so I can re-run the query without it while noting which ones weren't found.

Comment: Is it strictly mandatory to rescue in case a record with the given ids doesn't exist? Can't you use `where` and then check the difference by comparing the resulting ids with the given ones?

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is usually not a good idea

Comment: @SebastianPalma that was my plan if this was not possible. I was just curious if it was even because it seems like somewhere in the error this is tracked, I just was unable to figure out where.

Comment: I think that'd be very handy, but kind of too much for ActiveRecord and considering exceptions for control flow isn't advised and/or expensive, at least in Ruby.

Comment: I'd encourage you to add an answer to your question since it involves a common doubt to the problem. I don't see why it should be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong method. `.find` should be used to find specific records when you want the code to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. This is done to ensure that the record exists and avoid nil errors. Typically this is used to trigger a 404 response without repeating the same boilerplate:

```
def show
  @record = Record.find_by(id: params[:id])
  unless @record
    render file: 'public/404.html', status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Use `.find_by(id: id)` if you don't want the code to raise.

To fetch multiple records use where:

```
models = Model.where(id: [1,2,3])
```

If you want to determine which of those ids don't exist use an array diff:

```
bad_ids = [1,2,3] - models.ids
```